# Fixed Revolute Joint in farseer 3.5

Tags: farseer

Hi I'm currently new in farseer physics engine,
anyway,
I have read tutorial about farseer 3.31 here
http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2012/09/06/farseer-physics-3-3-1-and-xna-joints/

in the tutorial he's trying to attach/join paddle body to world withJointFactory.CreateFixedRevoluteJoint ,
unfortunately in farseer 3.5 there is no CreateFixedRevoluteJoint method, 
it's only CreateRevoluteJoint which is joint two bodies,
so how can I revolute joint one body to world object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a RevoluteJoint. And make your paddle rotate around another object. Like so:

```
Body motorPaddle = CreateMotorPaddle();  
Body motorPaddleAxle = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(World, 0.1f, 1f);  

var j = JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint  
    (  
        World,  
        motorPaddle,  
        motorPaddleAxle,  
        new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f),  
        new Vector2(-14.0f, 10.0f)  
        );  

// set speed and torque  
j.MotorSpeed = MathHelper.Pi;  
j.MotorImpulse = 100;   
j.MotorEnabled = true;  
j.MaxMotorTorque = 100;
```

More details [here](http://canofmortein.ayls.org/2013/10/14/simulating-fixed-and-line-joints-in-farseer-physics-engine-3-5/)